# How to sort Array data in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state, gql

I put data to `useState` in order that whenever data changes, UI changes.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState();
```

with this data, I run `FlatList`. (see `data` part)

```
    <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingBottom: 20,
      }}
      keyboardDismissMode={true}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={state}
      keyExtractor={(comment) => "" + comment.id}
      renderItem={renderComment}
    />
```

**And I want to sort this data by `createdAt` which is date.**

my data which is in `state` is `Array` composing of `object`s.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "__typename": "Comment",
    "createdAt": "1645612616365",
    "id": 434,
    "isMine": true,
    "payload": "가",
    "user": Object {
      "__typename": "User",
      "avatar": "https://chungchunonuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/1-1642681327283-%E1%84%80%E1%85%B5%E1%86%B7%E1%84%86%E1%85%B5%E1%84%89%E1%85%AE%E1%86%A8.jpeg",
      "username": "김미숙",
    },
  },
  Object {
    "__typename": "Comment",
    "createdAt": "1645589527805",
    "id": 431,
    "isMine": true,
    "payload": "음",
    "user": Object {
      "__typename": "User",
      "avatar": "https://chungchunonuploads.s3.amazonaws.com/avatars/1-1642681327283-%E1%84%80%E1%85%B5%E1%86%B7%E1%84%86%E1%85%B5%E1%84%89%E1%85%AE%E1%86%A8.jpeg",
      "username": "김미숙",
    },
  },
]
```

As I searched the way of sorting Array, it advised me to use `sort`.

So I made the function like below.

```
  const sortedState = state.sort(function (a, b) {
    parseInt(a.createdAt) - parseInt(b.createdAt) > 0;
  });
```

My plan was to put this `sortedSate` in FlatList.

```
    <FlatList
      data={sortedState}
    />
```

However, I've faced two error message.

**1) Attempted to assign readonly property.**

Probably it is because `state` is declared with `const`.
So I can't sort (change) it..

**2) undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.sort')**

I don't know why, but it seems I can't use `sort` method.

Please help me.

**+ when I call `setState`.**

when UI mounts first.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(updatePhoto?.seePhoto?.comments);
    register("comments", {
      required: true,
    });
  }, [state, updatePhoto, register]);
```

when I edit comment.

```
  const updateEditComment = (cache, result) => {
    const {
      data: {
        editComment: { error, ok, id },
      },
    } = result;
    if (ok) {
      refetch();
      setState(updatePhoto);
      textRef.current.clear();
    }
  };
  const onEditValid = async ({ comments }) => {
    const commentId = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@commentId");
    await editCommentMutation({
      variables: {
        id: parseInt(commentId),
        payload: comments,
      },
      update: updateEditComment,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are calling `setState`?

Comment: I add that on my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the data before you render it in the FlatList.

I've refactored your sort function to

```js
const getSortedState = (data) => data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.createdAt) - parseInt(b.createdAt));
```

```js
const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
  if(state) {
    return getSortedState(state);
  }

  return state;
}, [state]);

<FlatList
  data={sortedItems}
/>
```

Example [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/_0NWsoMB2).

Comment: ah I should've sorted data before calling it. thanks I understand.

Comment: @hyejung - I've refactored my answer to sort the data before you render it in the FlatList instead of sorting before you set the state.

Comment: Thanks I understand what you mean, but when I applied it, error comes => `Attempted to assign to readonly property`

Comment: I've attached a minimal Snack to the answer with the above code.

Comment: but I still face the same error T_T